# .flex-grow-1 on react-bootstrap <Row> not filling vertical space

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox, react-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get .flex-grow-1 in Bootstrap 4.6.0 (with react-bootstrap 1.5.2) to get a  component on my layout to expand to fill the remaining vertical space available.

```
"bootstrap": "^4.6",
"react-bootstrap": "1.5.2",
```

The following code produces a wireframe of the screen layout that I am trying to build.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import './SingleSignIn.scss'


class SignUpLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { country } = this.state;
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col id="left-column" className="grid bg-warning" style={{height: "100vw"}}>
          <Row className="grid flex-nowrap">
            <Col className="grid">
              {/* left margin */}
            </Col>
            <Col className="grid" xs={6} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "80px"}}>
                Welcome To:
              </Row>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "125px"}}>
                logo goes here
              </Row>
            </Col>
            <Col className="grid">
              {/* right margin */}
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row id="body" className="grid bg-danger flex-grow-1 flex-nowrap">
            <Col className="grid">
              {/* body left margin */}
            </Col>
            <Col className="grid" xs={10} sm={10} md={8} lg={8} xl={8}>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "10%"}}>
                e-mail input
              </Row>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "10%"}}>
                company name input
              </Row>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "10%"}}>
                country input
              </Row>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "10%"}}>
                phone number
              </Row>
              <Row className="grid" style={{height: "10%"}}>
                get started button
              </Row>
            </Col>
            <Col className="grid">
              {/* body right margin */}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
        <Col id="right-column" className="grid" style={{height: "100vw"}}>
          Right Column
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

export default SignUpLayout;
```

My intention is to get the  component identified as #body to grow vertically to fill the remaining vertical space available on the viewport. I'm using the `.flex-grow-1` class to try to accomplish this based on other similar posts that I came across in my search but it's not having the desired effect.

The resulting wireframe layout that I get from the above code is the following:
[image: layout wireframe]

Thanks in advance for the pointers.

Comment: I've sorted out my immediate problem by reserving proportional height for both the header and body sections of the layout using the min-height % property. That said, I'll leave the question open to see if there are other better alternatives.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it to resolve this question. Nothing stops others from posting additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a simmilar issue. I found a solution using bootstrap 5.3.2 and react-bootstrap 2.9.0. Hope it helps someone. :)

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <Container fluid={true} className="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <Row>
        <Col
          sm={3}
      
          css={css`
            background-color: red;
          `}
        >A</Col>
        <Col
          sm={6}
          css={css`
            background-color: green;
          `}
        >
          B
        </Col>
        <Col
          sm={3}
          css={css`
            background-color: blue;
          `}
        >C</Col>
      </Row>

      <Row className="flex-grow-1">
        <Col
          sm={3}
          css={css`
            background-color: pink;
          `}
        ></Col>
        <Col
          sm={6}
          css={css`
            background-color: yellow;
          `}
        ></Col>
        <Col
          sm={3}
          css={css`
            background-color: purple;
          `}
        ></Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col
          sm={12}
          css={css`
            background-color: grey;
          `}
        >Footer</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the result: [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhpEh.png)